# Android GLSL testing

Tags: android, glsl

Recently I faced with fragment shader compilation error on particular devices (on %90 compilation passed successfully)

1. What is the general approach for testing shaders?
2. I there any service which can help test shader compilation on different android devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found such kind tool from google on github [`shaderc`](https://github.com/google/shaderc) but didn't tried yet

**Updated**

Finally I used `glslValidate` tool and written [`simple gradle 'plugin'`](https://gist.github.com/CAMOBAP/0a31ea4f4752c5241e6e7bb72e73e38c)